# Method that returns 'n'th prime

Tags: ruby

First post here. I'll cut to the chase: why does this method work? I've been staring at it for the last hour trying to make sense of it, but I think what's confusing me is that there are just tons of variables.

Can anybody help explain it to me, perhaps line by line? Assume that **is_prime?(i)** is a previous method that tests if a certain number is a prime number. Thank you!

```
def nth_prime(n)

  prime_num = 0

  i = 2

  while true
     if is_prime?(i)             
        prime_num += 1           
        if prime_num == n         
           return i                
        end
     end
     i += 1                     
  end
end
```

Comment: I count only 3 variables. I would hardly consider that "tons of variables". What makes you think this method works? Have you done tests with it? Which part don't you understand? Which part do you understand? Your question is too open/broad as it is. You should narrow it down to specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming some variables and starting at `current_number == 0` to make it clear we're going through every number one by one.

```
def nth_prime(n)

  prime_count = 0  #keeps track of how many primes we have so far
  current_num = 0  #current number

  while true
     if is_prime?(current_num)             
        prime_count += 1           
        if prime_count == n         
           return current_num                
        end
     end
     current_num += 1                     
  end
end
```

#### What's going on?

As I say, we're going through all the numbers from `0` until the nth prime is found using a **while-loop** and `current_num += 1`.

If the `current_num` is prime our `prime_count` goes up by 1 which corresponds to the 1st prime etc. If the `prime_count` is then also equal to `n` we return `current_num` which will be the nth prime.

Comment: Thank you so much sagarpandya82! This absolutely did it for me.

Comment: Thanks @Andy. I made a small error in my description saying the while-loop goes from 0 to n which was incorrect, but I've fixed it now. If it's any consolation I found your code difficult to understand too so don't be too disheartened.

Answer (score 3):

Your method `is_prime?` could be written

```
require 'prime'

def is_prime?(n)
  Prime.prime?(n)
end
```

See the doc [Prime::is_prime?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime-3F).

Let's now add some `puts` statements to see what's going on with your code.

```
def nth_prime(n)
  prime_num = 0
  i = 2
  puts "i=#{i}"
  while true
    puts "  is_prime?(#{i})=#{is_prime?(i)}"
    if is_prime?(i)             
      prime_num += 1
      puts "  prime_num=#{prime_num}"           
      puts "  prime_num==#{n}: #{prime_num==n}"           
      if prime_num == n
        puts "Found #{n}th prime!"         
        return i
      end
    end                
    i += 1
    puts "i=#{i}"
  end
end
```

Then

```
nth_prime(3)
```

prints the following.

```
i=2
  is_prime?(2)=true
  prime_num=1
  prime_num==3: false
i=3
  is_prime?(3)=true
  prime_num=2
  prime_num==3: false
i=4
  is_prime?(4)=false
i=5
  is_prime?(5)=true
  prime_num=3
  prime_num==3: true
Found 3th prime!
  #=> 5
```

If you step through the code and compare the statements with the above printed results you should be able to understand the operations that are performed. Please let me know in a comment if that answers your question.

Here's how you might tighten up your code.

```
def nth_prime(n)
  prime_count = 0
  i = 1
  until prime_count == n
    i += 1
    prime_count += 1 if is_prime?(i)
  end
  i
end

nth_prime(4) #=> 7
```

The following is a more Ruby-like approach to the problem.

```
require 'prime'

def nth_prime(n)
  return 2 if n==1
  enum = Prime.each
  (n-1).times { enum.next }
  enum.next
end
```

See [Prime#each](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-each) and [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

```
nth_prime(1)      #=> 2 
nth_prime(2)      #=> 3 
nth_prime(3)      #=> 5 
nth_prime(4)      #=> 7 
nth_prime(10_000) #=> 104729
```

Comment: perhaps just `n.prime?` for your `is_prime?(n)` method?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 is suggesting that I add a method `prime?` to the class `Fixnum`. That certainly could be done, but I prefer not to "monkey-patch" (modifying a built-in class) unless there is a compelling reason to do so, which is not the case here.

Comment: the `prime?` method is included in `prime.rb`. `n.prime? #=> boolean`.

Comment: @sagarpandya82, I knew that two days ago, but since forgot. Readers, sagar is reminding me that, in addition to adding the `Prime` class, `require 'prime'` adds the method `prime?` to the `Fixnum` class. Or was that the `Integer` class?. Let's check: `3.method(:prime?).owner #=> Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's break it down:

The basic algorithm here is that we loop over every single number greater than 1, checking each for primality until the nth prime is found. The variable `prime_num` (though poorly named) actually contains a count of the prime numbers thus far discovered. Thus, when it equals the function parameter `n`, the function will return the corresponding prime. The variable `i` serves merely to hold the number being checked - initially, it's 2, and gets incremented by 1 each time it goes through the loop. Thus, when the value of `i` is prime, the value of `prime_num` is incremented, and when `prime_num` hits the magic `n`, the value of `i` (which is prime at that point) is returned.

It's not a terribly efficient algorithm, but it'll do the job, and isn't terribly hard to understand. As has been said elsewhere, however, it's recommended to use the standard library functions where possible.